# Simple algebra Doubt while solving number theory question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$n(n+1)(n-1)(3n+6)-4n(n+1)(n-1)$

$3n(n+1)(n-1)(n+2)-4n(n+1)(n-1)$

How $ (3n+1) $ bracket is worked in step $2$?

Comment: What $3n+1$? In step 2, a 3 was factored out of $(3n+6)$.

Comment: There is no $(3n+1)$ step here, In second step 3 has been taken common from the term $(3n+6)$. Simple!

Comment: Ohkay. I got it